# Which equality check will be executed in `SetEquals` for the elements?

Tags: c#, equals

We have the [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096.aspx) method to check different set types for equality. But what equality test will be executed on the elements? Will `Equals` or `ReferenceEquals` be used?

In the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096.aspx) it just states:

> Determines whether the current set and the specified collection
>   contain the same elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's "the one that the set uses to consider element equality", i.e. the same one used for `Add` and `Contains`. So for example:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "abc", "def"
};
var list = new List<string> { "ABC", "DEF" };
Console.WriteLine(set.SetEquals(list)); // True
```